# How can I compile Android applications?

Tags: compatibility, android, server

I want to use the pi as a continuous integration server. One type of the software are Android applications. Is it possible to have the Android SDK or something similar to compile Android apps?

I didn't find the Android SDK for arm on the official site. But for example there exists the AIDE app, where apps are compiled on an Android phone itself.

Disclaimer: I *don't* want to install Android as operating system on the pi.

Comment: Have you got CIS running on the Pi already?

Comment: The existence of compile-on-the-device Android tools demonstrates that it is *possible*.  The more important question is if it is worthwhile (worth the trouble to set up) - it would not be particularly fast, and if you don't want to install most of Android you get little benefit for testing from having an ARM CPU.  Something based on a customized Android build that could do testing (in a chroot?) could be interesting though.  But most android devices will have higher performance and resources than the pi; the main thing you get with the pi is wired ethernet for reliability.

Comment: @ppumkin No but I plan on using Jenkins, which is possible as posted in a other thread. I would install it when Oracle delivers a Raspbian friendly Java VM. So for now I'm doing preparation for that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The question I'm asking myself is, how difficult is it to set it up. Or is it just compiling the source (whereever to get it from).

Comment: If you are willing to install Android, probably fairly straightforward unless you run into lack of RAM; if not, you would have to get a java compiler working then recompile all of the android tools like dx.  What advantage do you see which would result from working through all of that, vs using a conventional server, fractional cloud server, or even an android device?  What are you going to do with the code once it is built?

Comment: @ChrisStratton A simple server running at home, where I have full access too and don't cost monthly money(except one euro per month for electricity)

Comment: Has anybody a hint where to find the Android SDK sources? On http://source.android.com/ I only find the sources for the specific android versions (2.2, 4.0 ...)

Comment: I played with the source a bit, but without any knowledge about the android source tree it's too much hassle to do. So for now I'm giving up :(

Comment: No sure I understand what you mean by running a simple server. You mean a fileserver or a webserver?

I usually compile Android apps on my Windows 7 PC and then put the .apk files on a normal webserver that has the .apk mimetype configured (as its not a default filetype for most webservers).

Comment: I want to commit my code in the repository and it will be automatically compiled and tests are run on the Continous Integration server (like Jenkins). It was just exciting if I can do that. And I would have a nice purpose for my Pi.

Comment: @AwesomeUser No. Afaik it's still impossible to compile a android application on Raspbian. It maybe possible, but it needs someone with depth knowledge of Android SDK to set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is no supported compilation available of Android SDK for ARM.

It maybe possible to do this, but this has to be done by someone with knowledge of Android build system.

Again clarification: I'm not talking about installing Android itself on the Pi. I'm talking to install the SDK on Raspbian to build Android application like in the development.

Comment: Hi, do you know if there still no arm SDK?

Answer (score -4):

Oracle released arm java jre and jdk!
links: 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1328488

once i rigged android sdk for armv6 from source but i forget how.

Comment: This answer is not particularly helpful in relation to the question, and the spelling and grammar seem off. However, you can still improve your answer by clicking the small edit link underneath.