# Is there a way to compile Android apps?

Tags: android

I have a Jenkins server running successful on my rpi and now I wonder if I can build Android applications with it. I know it is a duplicate question to this one ([How can I compile Android applications?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/how-can-i-compile-android-applications)), but this question is 2 years old and times have changed. Now we are able to run Oracle Java with pretty good performance on arm processors.

Is there a way to compile Android apps on the pi these days? I just can't find anything helpful on the web.

Comment: There is a sdk for linux. So i bet it should be possible.

Comment: Yeah but there is no sdk for arm processors as far as I know

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry. The closest I found was http://www.timelesssky.com/blog/building-android-sdk-build-tools-aapt-for-debian-arm

Answer (score 1):

While anything is possible with enough work at it I'm going to say 'no' on this one - There is no (reasonable) way to do this.

I was looking for the same thing as soon as the Pi2 came out, but due to the arm processor the Linux SDK is not usable, and to the best of my knowledge they have no intention of making one because quite frankly they lack the horsepower for many of the SDK tasks, such as Virtual Devices and even just running the IDE would likely be painful.

One thing you can do though is develop a lot of your code on the Pi, then shift over to the SDK on a full PC when you have most of your work functional - I am undergoing a similar process as I work on a small game for Android and am able to do virtually all development via a text console until it is time to build a GUI around a nearly-completed program.

Enjoy the Pi, but recognize that it has its own limitations. Also, you could always build a cool program for the Pi instead!